# Firebase Dynamic Links opens DL hierarchy and does not launch the flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have integrated Firebase Dynamic Links into my Flutter app, but unfortunately, it is not working as expected. After creating the dynamic link, when I try to open it, it shows me the Firebase Dynamic Links hierarchy and does not launch the app.

[image]

Here is my Android Manifest file

```
<activity>

...
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
  
                    <data android:scheme="http" />
                    <data android:scheme="https" />

                    <data android:host="domain.online/link" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This is the code used to create the dynamic link

```
static const _baseUrl = 'https://mydomain.online/link';

print('$_baseUrl$path?$queryParam=$value');
      var parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
        uriPrefix: _baseUrl,
        link: Uri.parse('$_baseUrl/users?uid=$value'),
        androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
          packageName: 'com.company.appname',
          minimumVersion: 0,
        ),
        iosParameters: const IOSParameters(
            bundleId: 'com.company.appname',
            minimumVersion: '0',
            appStoreId: 'appstoreid'),
      );
      final shortLink =
          await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(parameters);
      var shortUrl = shortLink;
      print('short link ==== ${shortUrl.previewLink.toString()}');
      return shortUrl.previewLink.toString();
```

and the base URL is added in Firebase Dynamic Links service.
[image]

Does anyone knows what might be the issue and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance